# Matching time in python from the text file

Tags: python

I want to match the time variable in the given text file and wanted to read the file from there.Any idea what i am doing wrong here?(i am new too python)

```
time = '05:48:19'

print (time)
with open( "PSC-CIPDiameter_8.1_A_1.stat.0" ) as f:
        line = f.readline()
        count=1
        while line:
                print ("Line %s : %s" % (count,line.strip()))
                line=f.readline()

                timenow = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%H:%M:%S')
                if(time  == timenow):

                        print "Read line: %s" % (line)
                        count=count+1
```

Comment: Post a sample of `PSC-CIPDiameter_8.1_A_1.stat.0`

Comment: you can debug by printing timenow. My initial thinking is time is string and timenow  is datetime

Comment: what is the value of `time` and `timenow`, also time seems to be set in the begining and not updated within the loop, print the value of time and timenow before the `if `statement and do some debugging that way, if you are still unable to find the problem, update the question with results and ping me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we could make this code a little bit more pythonic. As you said you're new to python, there are probably a few batteries that you didn't know came included with the language environment ;)

```
time = '05:48:19'
print(time)
with open("PSC-CIPDiameter_8.1_A_1.stat.0") as f:
    for count, line in enumerate(f):
        print("Line {} : {}".format(count, line.strip()))
        timenow = datetime.datetime.strptime(line, '%H:%M:%S')
        if(time == timenow):
            print("Read line: {}".format(line))
```

So, your equality test is never `True` because you are testing the **string** `time` against the **datetime object** `timenow` that you instantiated using `datetime.datetime.strptime`. If you want to compare both you should probably make `time` a datetime object by instantiating it like this:

```
time = datetime.datetime.strptime('05:48:19', '%H:%M:%S')
```